How to best photograph very large carpets from a horizontal position
I have several carpets all approx. 8m x 5.5m which can only be photographed indoors. My plan is to photograph them horizontally in sections and then stitch  -  how best do I obtain continuity with each image taken? My thoughts are to shoot the shorter 5.5m width in sections[from either right to left or visa versa] roll down the next area and shoot the same amount of images with plenty of overlap. And continue until the whole carper is photographed.

Does this answer your question: How do I set up my studio for shooting large rugs from the ceiling?, or What is the best techniques to photograph large rugs?, or Setup for taking photos of large flat surfaces (maps/plans/textiles) at limited distance

Panorama software can be told that the pictures are taken with parallel motion. Your main problem is going to be the light direction that has to be the same on the overlapping areas.

Lighting isn't the problem, it's making sure the camera is parallel to the carpet during the shooting process as the tripod is moved from the 'starting position' all the way across during the multi exposures
